# MERGE creates multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following expression:

```
MERGE (d:Day { day: "1" }) CREATE (a:Test { url:"unique1" })
```

In the database there are already three nodes that matches `(d:Day { day: "1" })`

If I execute the above expression and after that execute

```
MATCH (a:Test { url:"unique1" }) return count(a)
```

I can see that three test nodes have been created. Why is this?

Secondly if I want to create a:Test and d:Day, if the node doesn't exist, how do I do that in one expression (want to use the rest API and don't want to make two round trips).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well MERGE works like MATCH or CREATE, so if he found 3 nodes day:1, he will CREATE test 3 nodes as much times he founds the day nodes.

Maybe you can simply do :

```
MERGE (d:Day { day: "1" })
MERGE (a:Test { url:"unique1" })
```

Answer (score 0):

dJens,

If you only want to create a Test node in your example above when you have created a Day node, do a query like this:

```
MERGE (d:Day {day : '1'})
ON CREATE SET d.new = 1
WITH d
WHERE d.new = 1
MERGE (a:Test {url : 'unique1'})
REMOVE d.new
```

This will only create a Test node if a Day node was created, and only if the Test node doesn't already exist. If you always want to create a Test node when a Day node is created, you can replace the second MERGE with CREATE.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Christophe's answer seems to fix my issue